# Obtener atributo (data-timestamp) con Axios y Cheerio

Tags: nodejs, axios

estoy con un problema, tengo un pequeño codigo para obtener los partidos desde una web, pero tambien quiero obtener la hora en la que se juega dicho partido, en la pagina se encuentra en un atributo, por ejemplo: `<div data-timestamp="1633136700"></div>`. Bien, yo necesito obtener eso, pero no logro hacerlo, asi tengo el codigo:

```
var http = require("http");
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const url = "spain/primera-division/";
const SCRAPING_URL = "https://m.livesoccertv.com/es/competitions/" + url;

(async () => {
  const response = await axios
    .get(SCRAPING_URL)
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  const results = [];

  if (response) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response);
    /*OBTIENE EL SPAN QUE CONTIENE LOS NOMBRES DE LOS EQUIPOS */
    $("span").each(function () {
      results.push($(this).text());
    });
    /* PRUEBA
    $("div[data-timestamp]").each(function () {
      results.push($(this).text());
    });*/
  }
  const preResults = results.filter((data) => data != "");

  const resultsFiltrados = [];

  for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    resultsFiltrados.push(
      `${preResults[3 + i * 2]} vs ${preResults[4 + i * 2]}`
    );
  }

  //create a server object:
  http
    .createServer(function (req, res) {
      var tex = "test";
      res.write(tex); //write a response to the client
      res.end(); //end the response
    })
    .listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
  function log(socket, data) {
    console.log(resultsFiltrados);
    socket.emit("message", resultsFiltrados);
  }
  console.log(resultsFiltrados);
})();
```

Esto imprime:

```
[
  'Athletic Club vs Deportivo Alavés',
  'Osasuna vs Rayo Vallecano',
  'Mallorca vs Levante'
]
```

Y aca es donde necesito que imprima adelnte de cada partido el data timestamp, por ejemplo:

```
[
  '1633136700', 'Athletic Club vs Deportivo Alavés',
  '1633136700', 'Osasuna vs Rayo Vallecano',
  '1633136700', 'Mallorca vs Levante'
]
```

O tambien puede estar en otro array, pero no logre hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listo:

```
$("div").each(function (i, e) {
  title.push($(e).attr("data-timestamp"));
});
```